# Can I delete my own Question or Answer that already has comments?

Tags: support, comments, self-delete

I know you cannot delete your question if it already has answer(s) with votes.
But can you delete your question or answer if someone else has already added comments on it?

Answer (score 4):

Comments do not affect the requirements for the deletion of a post. So if you satisfy all of the other requirements to delete the post, you can do it whether there are 0 comments, 100 comments, dozens of comments scored at 50 or higher, and any such combination.

Comment: I was getting ready to do *science*, but then you come along with your *facts*!

Comment: Wouldn't it be rude and inconsiderate to all who commented if I just delete the questions and all their comments are gone?

Comment: @Dmitri Technically, the only reason you delete a post is because it is not useful to keep around. The value of a comment is usually related to the value of the accompanying post. If the post is not useful to keep around, most people are fine with their comments being lost because they cease to be necessary. People would probably find it rude if you were doing this *just* to delete their comments, but mostly that doesn't happen.